# Macro to Copy Data and iterate though a series of records

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of records that I need to reorganize. They are in the format below. ID is the number that corresponds with the following 5 rows. I need this number to exist in column A beside each of the rows with their corresponding ID number.. 
I need the ID number to exist in column A like seen in the second image. This needs to be done using VBA in a macro as there are over 100 records.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm not sure the best way to reference the ID field without doing it 1 by 1 like the code below...

[image: Stage 1]

[image: Final Stage]

```
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A5"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A5").Select
Range("A7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R6C[2]"
Range("A7").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A7:A10"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A7:A10").Select
Range("A12").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R11C[2]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions: 
Your data groups will be present in column "B", beginning in row 1, and consist of 4 additional records in a worksheet called "Sheet1"

```
Public Sub AutoFillRecordGroup()

Dim irecordgroup as Integer
Dim xlrange as Excel.Range
Dim varcell as Variant
Set xlrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1048576").End(xlup).Address)

irecordgroup = 1
For Each varcell in xlrange
If varcell.value = "ID" Then
varcell(1,-1).value = irecordgroup
varcell(2,-1).value = irecordgroup
varcell(3,-1).value = irecordgroup
varcell(4,-1).value = irecordgroup
irecordgroup = irecordgroup + 1
End If 
Next varcell

End Sub
```

or

```
Public Sub AutoFillRecordGroup()

Dim irecordgroup as Integer
Dim xlrange as Excel.Range
Dim varcell as Variant
Set xlrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1048576").End(xlup).Address)

irecordgroup = 1
For Each varcell in xlrange
If varcell.value = "ID" Then
varcell(1,-1).value = varcell(0,1).value
varcell(2,-1).value = varcell(0,1).value
varcell(3,-1).value = varcell(0,1).value
varcell(4,-1).value = varcell(0,1).value
irecordgroup = irecordgroup + 1
End If 
Next varcell

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of assuming the ID is consecutive I would change it to get the value of id from column C.

Comment: Updated with a second option per Kevin's note.

Comment: @cronos2546 seem to get a runtime error at the line where you are setting xl range..

Comment: What's the name of your sheet?